# subprocess.Popen and py2exe

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, py2exe

I'm using a wrapper library to send commands to a windows executable and the python script works great.

But when I convert the script with py2exe I get errors from the spawned process saying that the respective command does not exist.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(args, 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Some of the commands arrive unscathed until one of them is missing the first letter.

```
process.stdin.write(data)
process.stdin.flush()
```

and if e.g. **Command** is sent

> Unknown Action: ommand

---

***edit***

```
class Command(object):

    def __init__(self, app, cmdstr):
        if isinstance(cmdstr, six.text_type):
            cmdstr = cmdstr.encode('ascii')
        self.app = app
        self.cmdstr = cmdstr
        self.status_line = None
        self.data = []

    def execute(self):
        self.app.write(self.cmdstr + b'\n')

        while True:
            line = self.app.readline()
            if not line.startswith('data:'.encode('ascii')):
                self.status_line = line.rstrip()
                result = self.app.readline().rstrip()
                return self.handle_result(result.decode('ascii'))

            self.data.append(line[6:].rstrip('\n\r'.encode('ascii')))

    def handle_result(self, result):
        if result == '' and self.cmdstr == b'Quit':
            return
        if result == 'ok':
            return
        if result != 'error':
            raise ValueError('received: {0}'.format(result))

        msg = b'[no error message]'
        if self.data:
            msg = ''.encode('ascii').join(self.data).rstrip()
        raise CommandError(msg.decode('ascii'))
```

```
class Application(object):
    executable = 'myApp'
    args = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.sp = None
        self.spawn_app()

    def spawn_app(self):
        args = [self.executable] + self.args
        self.sp = subprocess.Popen(
            args,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )

    def close(self):
        self.sp.kill()

    def write(self, data):
        self.sp.stdin.write(data)
        self.sp.stdin.flush()

    def readline(self):
        return self.sp.stdout.readline()
```

```
def exec_command(cmdstr):
    c = Command(app, cmdstr)
    c.execute()
    return c

# all b'...' work
exec_command(b'Quit')
exec_command(b'Enter')
# this seems to work as well
command = 'Connect({0})'.format(host).encode('ascii')
exec_command(command)
# those two don't
exec_command('Move({0}, {1})'.format(y, x).encode('ascii'))
exec_command('String("{0}")'.format(text).encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Could you share a complete script which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks. Or is there maybe a signal I can send before the command, that doesn't interfere with the process? I think space leads to errors.